# triggering a function after the finish of specific Request in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a complex **scraping** application in Scrapy that run at multiple stages (each stage is a function calling the next stage of scraping and parsing). the spider try to download multiple targets and each target consists of large number of files. what i need to do is after downloading all the files of a target is calling some function that process them and it cannot process them partially it needs the whole set of files for the target at the same time. is there a way to do it ?

Comment: What about `def closed(self, reason):` in your `pipelines.py`?

Comment: but this will run only after the spider is closed right ? but in this case i need something like that but after each group of request not the entire spider @gangabass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot wait until the whole spider is finished, you will have to write some logic in an item pipeline that keeps track of what you have scraped, and executes a function then.
Below is some logic to get you started: it keeps track of the number items you scraped per target, and when it reaches 100, it will execute the target_complete method. Note that you will have to fill in the field 'target' in the item of course.

```
from collections import Counter

class TargetCountPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.target_counter = Counter()
        self.target_number = 100

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        target = item['target']
        self.target_counter[target] += 1
        if self.target_counter[target] >= self.target_number:
            target_complete(target)
        return item

    def target_complete(self, target):
        # execute something here when you reached the target
```

Comment: does that means for the entire spider there is going to be exactly one instance of this class ?

Comment: There will be 1 instance of the item pipeline when you run the spider. every item scraped will go through this pipeline.

Comment: that's great I guess it will work thanks for the response